# Why was Eugene Levy not cast in American Pie Presents: Girls' Rules?

Tags: character, casting, american-pie

Eugene Levy as character "Noah Levenstein" (Jim's dad) was cast in all of the American Pie and American Pie Presents movies *except* the most recent one: American Pie Presents: Girls' Rules.

Since he was included in the other films where Jim was not present, why was he not in American Pie Presents: Girls' Rules? Did he retire?

I just can't find that answer anywhere. [This](https://screenrant.com/american-pie-girls-rules-movie-eugene-levy-absence/) is the closest I get.

Comment: That link is one of the most hilarious examples of click bait I've seen! The title promises the answer to your question but it's basically just "I dunno" surrounded by some vague highlights of Eugene's career that nobody who cared could possibly not already know...

Comment: The first rule of Girls' Rules is: you do not tell Eugene Levy about Girls' Rules.

Answer (score 2):

The filming dates for *American Pie Presents: Girls' Rules* conflicted with Levy's promotional tour for Schitt's Creek. IMDB lists the [production dates](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11771594/locations/#:%7E:text=Oct%2016%2C%202019%20%2D%20Nov%2011%2C%202019) for the film as...

> Oct 16, 2019 - Nov 11, 2019

... but during that same period Levy was doing multiple dates for his [*Schitt’s Creek: Up Close & Personal* tour](https://www.forbes.com/sites/loisaltermark/2019/10/23/ew-david-schitts-creek-up-close-and-personal-sells-out-at-the-cosmopolitan-of-las-vegas/?sh=7254847130ac) which took place in [September](https://twitter.com/Realeugenelevy/status/1172708758520074240), [October](https://twitter.com/Realeugenelevy/status/1191905612290043904) and November.

> As the show heads into its sixth and final season, the series
> creators/stars Eugene Levy and Dan Levy, along with other cast
> members, will be be taking the show on the road for the “Schitt’s
> Creek: Up Close & Personal” tour this fall for a “live, interactive
> evening that promises to be fun and insightful while giving fans an
> insider’s look into the making of the series.” Dates include Denver,
> Las Vegas, Vancouver, Atlanta, Brooklyn (Kings Theatre on 11/15) and
> Atlantic City (Caesars on 11/16). Tickets for the Kings Theatre and
> Caesars shows go on sale Friday, September 13 at 10 AM, with various
> presales beforehand.
>
> <sub><sup>['Schitt's Creek' cast going on 'Up Close & Personal' tour this fall](https://www.brooklynvegan.com/schitts-creek-cast-going-on-up-close-personal-tour-this-fall/)</sup></sub>

---

As to why he didn't make more effort to move his schedule around, it's fairly telling that he describes Schitt’s Creek as his most recognisable role and that the 'whole American Pie thing' was becoming 'tedious'.

> **Q. What do you get recognised most for nowadays? Is it still American
> Pie?**
>
> **EL:** Now it’s Schitt’s Creek. All over the world. People came up and
> talked about the show in pretty much any location we visited. The
> American Pie thing got a bit tedious. People would bring me apple pie
> every time I went into a restaurant or to a wedding. Which is kind of
> funny, but it did happen a lot.
>
> <sub><sup>[Eugene Levy: The Schitt’s Creek star on his unlikely new travelogue, the thrill of working with family and his pal Jennifer Coolidge stealing the show](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2023/mar/05/eugene-levy-reluctant-traveler-schitts-creek-interview)</sup></sub>